# Access object in AppDelegate from ViewController

Tags: swift, macos, viewcontroller, appdelegate

In **AppDelegate.swift** I've declared an NSStatusBar object like this:

```
var statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
statusItem.button?.title = "chess"
statusItem.button?.target = self
statusItem.button?.action = #selector(showSettings)
```

and works fine, but I want to change the title in the **viewController.swift**

I trying this (In view controller):

```
var appd = AppDelegate()
appd.statusItem.button?.title = "ELO: \(parsing2.chess_daily.last.rating)"
```

But the title not change... how can I do this???

Comment: Try creating a function in your `AppDelegate` that changes the title, and then call that from your vc: `AppDelegate().changeStatusTitle("ELO")`

Comment: I don't think that calling functions that belong to your AppDelegate from another class would be good coding style

Comment: Hi @Koen I get the same result as my code above

Comment: @RX9 the app delegate is the root singleton of the app that's there in large part to handle objects and functions that don't have any other better owning view controller. Accessing data from and calling functions in the app delegate is a very standard coding practice. The problem OP is having is that he isn't accessing the singleton instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the delegate object from `NSApplication`, the default initializer `AppDelegate()` creates a new unrelated instance.

```
let appDelegate = NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.statusItem.button?.title = "ELO: \(parsing2.chess_daily.last.rating)"
```